# kubectl query results in "unauthorized" with GCP cluster even after `get-credentials`

Tags: linux, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, authorization, gcloud

I get `You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` for commands like `kubectl get pods -A`  even after having followed many steps by step guides and tried various solutions. He is more detail on what I did and what works / does not work:

```
gcloud container clusters create <cluster_name> --zone <zone> --project <project_name>
minikube start
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --zone <zone> --project <project_name>
gcloud auth login
```

*Do login in browser*

Checking:

```bash
-> % kubectl config current-context
gke_<project_name>_<zone>_<cluster_name>
-> % curl http://localhost:8080/api/
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "xxx.xxx.x.x:8443"
    }
  ]
}%
-> % kubectl cluster-info     
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend:http/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

So this works. But what does not work:

```
-> % kubectl get pods -A
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

What gives?

I spent hours now trying to find a solution. The solutions I found reference `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

I don't have the directory `/etc/kubernetes`. (I do run Linux)

Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to run `kubecl get pods` in the cloudshell?

Comment: I think you're complicating your experience by running `minikube` (which possibly updates `KUBECONFIG`) and then `gcloud auth login` **after** you must already be logged in to be able to run `gcloud container clusters create` and `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`. It's good practice to provide minimally-reproducible examples so, please avoid the redundant (`minikube`, `kubectl proxy` and `gcloud auth login`) and simply `gcloud container clusters create`, `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`, `kubectl config current-context` (if you wish) and then `kubectl get nodes`.

Comment: @DazWilkin It also does not work with not running minikube. Also, I am now confused as to how these are "redundant:", especially `kubectl proxy`. How is that redundant? As for the order of the commands, I probably did `auth` first in the very beginning. I suppose all the other times I did were redundant in that sense.

Comment: @Adiii I am, yes.

Comment: It appears you've solved the issue. `kubectl proxy` is redundant because you do not need to run it in order to run e.g. `kubectl get pods`. Because w/ GKE, authentication leverages `gcloud`, running `gcloud auth login` **after** generating credentials (using it) for `kubectl` could possibly invalidate the `kubectl` credentials. Again, running `gcloud auth login` after the other commands is redundant. A minimally reproducible example should not include redundant commands. They complicate the question and they may create additional problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is: I was using `kubectl` as an alias for `minikube kubectl` but after removing the alias `which kubectl` shows `/home/<user>/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl`. Now everything seems to work.